# HTML div element

Tags: html

I have a div element that is defined on the top of the page and I have this another div element that is defined at the bottom of the page.... is there any way that I can define the first div element (at the top) as a child of the div element that is at the bottom.

The problem is I need a div in header in the header file (header.php) this div acts as a container for an JS, but once the data is loaded I want it to be displayed inside another div.

Would postponing the loading of JS till the middle section of page is advisable...

Comment: If the top div acts as both a container for your JS, and contains elements that need to be displayed inside another div, can you split it into two? In fact, Javascript does not need to be contained in a div at all (just use <script> tags). The downvote wasn't mine, by the way, but I speculate it was given because you posted no code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes: make the top div a child of the bottom div by placing the child within the markup of the parent, and use absolute positioning to move the child to the top.

Comment: Though if you must do this, there is probably something wrong with your design.

Answer (score 1):

No, because it's not a child of that DIV. If you want it to be a child, make it a child, and then alter it's position with CSS to be on the top of the page.

Answer (score 1):

No idea why you would want to do that but this markup should suffice:

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="main">
        <!-- Insert content, push off the top with "margin-top:150px", etc. -->
    </div>
    <div id="foot">
        <div id="head">
            <!-- Insert header stuff, position with "positon:absolute", etc. -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Tweak `width`, `height`, `margin` and `padding` of elements to taste.

Comment: I don't think that's what is being asked, but it is a bit confusing, so I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

No, though you can move it with JavaScript after the second element loads.

1. By "child" do you mean simply appears inside, yet the HTML is defined at the top?  If so, you could also possibly simply change the positioning via CSS.
2. Are you constrained to output the HTML for the first `div` at the top of the page for any reason?  The real solution here is to simply output elements where you actually want them.